# Regular expression to include brackets and exclude whitespaces

Tags: regex

Regex for a method name which will only contain one opening and one closing bracket and will not accept any white spaces. I tried this-

.*(((.*)))+

But it is accepting spaces also

Comment: Please post the code you are using, sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your question seems very legitimate but it should indeed be improved with examples. Examples what you expect and what you did not expect. Maybe you can even create an example at http://refiddle.com/

Answer (score -1):

`^\s` - will omit whitespace
use `\` in front of '(' and ')' to include since both are reserved so you need '\' to mention it's the character to match .

```
\(^\s\)
```